# Non-linear differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

non linear differential equation

$ ((y')^2)(y'')=1+(y')^2 $

I tried to use $y'=z$ , $z'=(dz/dy)z$

It dosen't work and I got $ y=0.5(z^2-\ln(z^2+1)) $

How can I got solution of y ?

plz..

Comment: What do you mean by "It dosen't work" ?

Comment: can't find y with that method

Comment: "I got $ y=0.5(z^2-\ln(z^2+1)) $" does not seem compatible with "can't find y".

Comment: cuz $z=y'$ so I thought that is not solution

Answer (score 2):

$$ ((y')^2)(y'')=1+(y')^2 $$
What you got is correct : $\quad y(z)=\frac12(z^2-\ln(z^2+1))+c_1 \quad;\quad z=\frac{dy}{dx}$

On the other hand : $\quad z^2z'=1+z^2\quad\implies\quad \frac{z^2}{1+z^2}dz=dx$

$x=\int\frac{z^2}{1+z^2}dz=z-\tan^{-1}(z)+c_2$

The solution is obtained on parametric form :
$$\begin{cases}
x(z)=z-\tan^{-1}(z)+c_2\\
y(z)=\frac12(z^2-\ln(z^2+1))+c_1
\end{cases}$$
It seems not possible to explicitly get $y(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! parametric form..!